# Interpretation of summations in regards to combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, summation

I've been studying for a final in combinatorics and ran into 3 different summations that have me stumped.

1) interpret the equation in terms of counting words. (Hint: $e^a$$e^b$$e^c$)

$$e^{3x} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty 3^k\frac{x^k}{k!}$$

2) interpret the equation in terms of counting words. What is $a_k$?

$$(e^x - 1)^3 = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k \frac{x^k}{k!}$$

3) in the equation, what does $a_k$ count?

$$(e^x - x - 1)^3 = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k \frac{x^k}{k!}$$

Any help would be much appreciated! Sorry for the difficult to read equations but I'm asking this from my phone and don't know how to put sigma symbols and subscript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equation (1) counts the number of words of length $k$ over the $3$-symbol alphabet $\{a,b,c\}$. This is obviously $3^k$, so the exponential generating function (egf) is $e^{3x}$, but you can also get this by taking the egf for words of length $k$ over a single symbol (there's only $1$ for each $k$, so the egf is $e^x$) and cubing it.

In equation (2), $a_k$ counts the number of words of length $k$ over three symbols in which each symbol occurs at least once.  To compute $a_k$, write $(e^x-1)^3=e^{3x}-3e^{2x}+3e^x-1$, to see that $a_0=0$ and $a_k=3^k-3(2^k)+3$ if $k>0$. You can also get the same result by inclusion/exclusion.

In equation (3), $a_k$ counts the number of words of length $k$ over three symbols in which each symbol occurs at least twice.